# Flutter snackbar throws render overflow error when displaying multiple lines of text

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

Is there a way to display multiple lines of text on a snackbar without it throwing a renderflex error?

[image]

I tried wrapping it with Flexible and Expanded widgets but both didn't help, I still get the error. The errorMessage received by the below method could be long sometimes.

```
  void displayMessage(context, errorMessage) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Expanded(
            child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.warning,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    size: 22,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 7,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    errorMessage,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 17,
                        color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include a demo image ? Removing `Expanded` works fine.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh just added the image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `Expanded` and wrap `Text` with `Flexible`,

```dart
 content: Row(
          children: [
            const Icon(
              Icons.warning,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 22,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 7,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                errorMessage,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error after the modification

Comment: check update answer